# Как соединить 2 виртуальные машины на 2х разных компьютерах в одну сеть?

Tags: сеть, virtualbox

Есть 2 компьютера, на каждом установлена виртуальная машина Oracle VirtualBox с операционной системой Windows XP. Нужно объединить эти две виртуальные машины в одну сеть, чтобы  между ними пинг шел ну и проводить кое-какие манипуляции.

Comment: Обоим машинам виртуальные сетевые карты в режим моста на сетевые карты хост-машин, плюс одна IP-подсеть.

Comment: Попробуйте через "внутреннюю сеть"

Answer (score 1):

На VMWare так делал, объединял в сеть два реальных и два виртуальных компьютера.
Виртуальные сетевые карты подключал в режиме моста, и всем четырем свой IP адрес и одну рабочую сеть назначал.
Все более чем работало.
Два Windows 7 и два Windows 98.
Программы из под Windows 98 по сети печатали на реальный компьютер (точнее на его принтер)